# Rolling period returns: number of 1-year, 3-year and 5-year performance

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

The past few hours I've been trying to figure out how I can measure the number of years a portfolio of stocks underperformed against a benchmark. I have 240 months of returns for my portfolio as well as for the benchmark:

> Portfolio return: -1,5%, 3,00%, -0,75%, ...
>
> Benchmark return:  -2,54%, 2,62% , -1,39%, ...

Right now I want to calculate how many 1-year, 3-year and 5-year periods appeared that the benchmark performed better than my portfolio.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please produce a reproducible example, with sample data and code that you already have. Otherwise without that it is difficult to know exactly what you want. I've had to download some of my own data for this.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

stocks <- c("AAPL", "JNJ", "BA", "MSFT", "C")

for (ticker in stocks) {
  if(ticker == stocks[1]){
    portfolio <- getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2000-01-01", to = "2019-12-31")[,6]
  }else{
    portfolio <- cbind(portfolio, getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2000-01-01", to = "2019-12-31")[,6])
  }
}

colnames(portfolio) <- stocks

portfolio_returns <- rowSums(Return.calculate(portfolio, method = "discrete")[-1]) / ncol(portfolio)
portfolio_returns <- xts(portfolio_returns, order.by = index(portfolio)[-1])

getSymbols('SPY', from = "2000-01-01", to = "2019-12-31")

benchmark <- Return.calculate(SPY[,6], method = "discrete")[-1]
```

That gives us a portfolio of five stocks with returns of that portfolio for 20 years. Next we count how many one, three and five year periods are in 20 years. For the three year period, since 20 years will give six 3 year period with a remainder, we use `floor` to get the whole number

```r
period_one <- nyears(portfolio_returns)
period_three <- floor(nyears(portfolio_returns) / 3)
period_five <- nyears(portfolio_returns) / 5

oneYear <- threeYear <- fiveYear <- 0
```

The last line initialises three variables which will save the number of years the benchmark outperformed the portfolio.

```r
Return.performance <- function(x, n, nperiods){

  periodYear <- 0

  periods <- seq(from = 1, by = 252*n, length.out = nperiods+1)

  num <- 1

  for (i in periods[-1]){
    pre_year <- periods[num]
    if(i==periods[length(periods)]) i <- nrow(x)
    temp <- Return.cumulative(x[pre_year:i])[,1] < Return.cumulative(x[pre_year:i])[,2]
    if(temp==TRUE) periodYear <- periodYear + 1 
    num <- num + 1 
  }

  return(periodYear)

}
```

The code is simple, since there are roughly 252 trading days in a year, I use that to create and index to extract each one year, three year and five year period in the loops. Alternatively, you can use "2000/2001", "2000/2003", "2000/2005", since these are xts objects. However, you'd have to convert to numeric to increment both start and end years then convert to character.

```r
assets <- cbind(portfolio_returns, benchmark)

Return.performance(assets, 1, period_one)
[1] 4
Return.performance(assets, 3, period_three)
[1] 1
Return.performance(assets, 5, period_five)
[1] 0
```

The portfolio I have has not underperformed in any five year period out of 4, only underperformed once in six 3 year periods, and underperformed just 4 times in 20 one year periods. Looks like I'm quite the stock picker! Alas no such thing as hindsight as a hedge fund manager :)